# What is the IObservable.Subscribe(IObserver<T> observer) overload for?

Tags: .net, system.reactive

When I am writing `.Subscribe` expressions I often find that Resharper has chosen the following overload for me, located in mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0:

```
namespace System
{
  public interface IObservable<out T>
  {
    IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T> observer);
  }
}
```

This seems very different from most overloads which take an `Action` and also it's coming from mscorlib and not `System.Reactive.*` which is where I expect most of the Reactive stuff to be.

What does this overload do?
How should it be used?
How does `IObserver<T>` relate to `Action`?
And why is this single overload in mscorlib?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To be clear, that isn't an overload, that's the core of Rx really. All the other `Subscribe` methods, and all other operators for that matter, that you're used to are really extension methods that ultimately call that.

If you look at early documentation or Rx, you'll see that the creators viewed it as the push-based side of LINQ. So a lot of things are the mirror image of what you see in LINQ. `IObservable` is the mirror of `IEnumerable`, and `IObserver` is the mirror of `IEnumerator`.

However, because push is the opposite of pull, so the Rx versions are the opposite of their pull-based counterpart:

- `IEnumerable` defines one method that produces an `IEnumerator`. `IObservable` defines one method that *takes in* an `IObserver`.
- If you think of `IEnumerator.MoveNext()` + `IEnumerator.Current` as one operation, that can return in one of three ways: next element returned, end of collection reached, or exception thrown. Similarly, the `IObserver` has to handle three cases: next element (`OnNext`), end of stream (`OnCompleted`), or exception (`OnError`).

The more familiar 'overloads' of `Subscribe` are really just extension methods that look something like this:

```
public static IDisposable Subscribe<T>(this IObservable<T> source, Action<T> onNext)
{
    return Subscribe(onNext, e => {/*onError */}, () => {/*onCompleted*/);
}

public static IDisposable Subscribe<T>(this IObservable<T> source, Action<T> onNext, Action<Exception> onError, Action onCompleted)
{
    source.Subscribe(new AnonymousObserver<T>(onNext, onError, onCompleted));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at `IObserver` you might see the reason. The interface contains three methods (or `Action`s), the most "used" of them being `OnNext`.

Now let's see the implementation of the overload for `Action` [here](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/blob/fa1629a1e12a8fc21c95aeff7863425c2485defd/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Observable.Extensions.cs#L46). The extension method actually generates `IObserver` for you by passing the provided `Action` as the `OnNext` semantics.

You can provide `Action`s for all interface method implementations if you wish to handle `OnError` and `OnCompleted` notifications.